# How to fix MethodNotAllowedHttpException error pagination laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have create a searsh view and i can go to the values in another page and it's working fine , I can see my values but when I have added pagination it's working again but when I press button number 2 of paination it's not working and it give me an error :
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('POST')) ...

My functions:

```
public function searsh()
  {
    return view('resultats.recherche');
  }


 public function show(Request $request)
  {

    $this->validate($request, [
      'cne' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    $exams = Exam::where('cne', $request->cne)->paginate(4);
    return view('resultats.index', compact('exams'));
  }
```

and this is my routes:
The first one that make me send a searsh request in db

```
  Route::get('/chercher', 'ExamsController@searsh')->name('display-cne-search');
Route::post('/resultat', 'ExamsController@show')->name('show-exams-cne-results');
```

and this is my view

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>

body{
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -o-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
background: url('image/t10.jpg');
}
.bling{
  background:url('image/background.jpg');
}
</style>
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')

@if($exams->isEmpty())
<div style="width:100%;height:100px;background-color:white">
<center>
  <p style="margin-top:50px;">Le cne que vous avez choisi est incorrecte entrer un autre cne svp <a href="/chercher">
    <br>
  <button  style="margin-top:5px"class="btn btn-primary">Par ici</button></a>
  </p>
</center>
</div>
@else
<div class="container">
  <div  class="row">
    <center><div class="col-md-12">
      <div style="border-radius:5px;background:url('image/background.jpg')">
      <center>
        <h2 style="color:white;font-weight: bold;padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;" > Historique des résultats de l'étudiant(e) {{$prenom}} {{$nom}} <br>
           CNE {{$cne}}</h2>


      </center>
      </div>
      <center><table style="background-color:white;border-radius:5px;"  class="table">
        <head>
        <tr>
          <th>Matiére</th>
          <th>Note</th>
          <th>Semestre</th>
          <th>Session</th>
          <th>Année</th>
          <th>Le prof vous a peut-être laissé une remarque</th>
          <th>Demande Vérification</th>
        </tr>
      </head>
      <body>
        @foreach($exams as $exam)
        <tr  class="{{$loop->index % 2==0 ? 'bling' : ''}}">
          <td>{{ $exam->matiere}}</td>
          <td>{{ $exam->note}}</td>
          <td>{{ $exam->sem}}</td>
          <td>{{ $exam->ses}}</td>
          <td>{{ $exam->an}}</td>
          <td>
          <center>
          <button type="button" value="{{$exam->remarque}}" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" onClick="document.getElementById('remarque').innerHTML=this.value">
            Remarque
          </button>
          </center>
          </td>
         <td>
          @if(!$exam->verification)
        <button  class="btn btn-succees" onclick="document.getElementById('verification-form-{{$exam->id}}').submit();" >
            Vérifier la note
          </button>
        <form id="verification-form-{{ $exam->id }}" action="{{ route('display-num-search', $exam ) }}" method="post">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
        </form>
          @elseif($exam->verification->etat=="En attente")
            <center> <a title="{{$exam->verification->etat}}" style="background-color:orange" class="btn-floating btn pulse"></a></center></p>
          @else
            <center><p> Verifié <i title="Note verifié par le professeur" class="fas fa-user-check"></i></p></center>
          @endif
        </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        <center>{{ $exams->links()}}</center>
      </body>
    </table></center>
<!-- modal remarque -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Remarque du prof</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div style="font-size:15px;font-weight: bold;" id="remarque"></div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div></center>
  </div>
</div>

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous">

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-trigger');
    var instances = M.Dropdown.init(elems, options);
  });

  // Or with jQuery

  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();

</script>

@endif
@endsection
```

Comment: How about `{{$exams-&gt;render()}}`?
Update: put your links out of the table code.

Comment: i have put it out of table still not working with render or links

Comment: Can you please paste the url of the page after the search is performed

Comment: Put if after table is closed

Comment: link after searsh from the first view
http://fsjes2.oo/resultat  
after i click on number 2 in pagination i get http://fsjes2.oo/resultat?page=2 with the error page

Comment: @mafortis the pagination links are after `foreach` loop, so it doesn't matter if it's inside the table.

Comment: @MehdiElAissi in your route, instread of `post` try `any`

Comment: @Saurabh I tryed Any instead of post  It's not working the page doesn't load

Comment: @saurabh it does matter, have you checked official docs of pagination? Links are after container is closed. `i used to have same issue before i just share my experience, you share yours bro.`

Comment: What if you use `simplePaginate(4)`? Still same error?

Comment: @mafortis yes still the same error

Answer (score 0):

POST requires a CSRF token everytime to process the request.

So, for performing a search and getting the pagination you can set the route as:

`Route::any('/resultat', 'ExamsController@show')->name('show-exams-cne-results');`

By this method, the first search performed is handled with POST method with the CSRF token and later for paginations, GET method is used.

EDIT: To make searches:

Change your route to GET.

`Route::get('/resultat', 'ExamsController@show')->name('show-exams-cne-results');`

Also, change the form method to GET

`<form id="verification-form-{{ $exam->id }}" action="{{ route('display-num-search', $exam ) }}" method="GET">`

Comment: Any didn't work when i set it instead of post the page doesn't load anymore when i click on number 2 in pagination

Comment: Okay, I think you should be using GET for search.

Comment: should i change post to get?

Comment: Yes change post to get in your route. I have updated my answer, reload please.

Comment: i tyred it also it's not working when i want to accees the view i get (1/1) MethodNotAllowedHttpException
 after i click searsh in the first view

Comment: In your form, `method="post"` is specified. It should be `method="GET"`

Comment: Change routes to GET and try this: `{{ $exams->appends(request()->input())->links() }}`